# How to load a Keras model in R on Windows?

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, h5py

I'm having a hard time to load a keras model (.h5) in R. This is the script that I tried:

```
library(keras)
new_model <- load_model_hdf5("model1.h5")
```

And the error message is:

```
Error in load_model_hdf5("model1.h5") : 
  The h5py Python package is required to save and load models
```

I also tried saving the model in a different format (save whole model), but got a different error message. This is what I tried:

```
new_model <- load_model_tf('model1')
```

and error message is:

```
Error in if (tensorflow::tf_version() < "2.0.0") stop("TensorFlow version >= 2.0.0 is requires to load models in the SavedModel format.",  : 
  argument is of length zero
```